# Why am I getting the error "Required Property Missing" when integrating Facebook Open Graph?

Tags: html, facebook, rdf, facebook-opengraph

I am attempting to integrate Facebook open graph into my site but I ran it through the URL Linter (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/lint) and I get the error: "Required Property Missing, og:title is required"

I'm concerned it's because my html is not valid or is missing something:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" dir="ltr" lang="en-US" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Grahame Thomson</title>
<meta property="og:title" content="Grahame" />
<meta property="og:type" content="website" />
<meta property="og:url" content="http://www.grahamethomson.com" />
<meta property="og:image" content="http://grahamethomson.com/images/me.jpg" />
<meta property="og:site_name" content="grahamethomson_test.com" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Student and web designer living in Scotland."/>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Site link:

http://grahamethomson.com/test/open_graph.html

Comment: Please provide the url you are trying to fix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are defining the homepage as the url to use with `og:url`, when you should be using the current URL or leave it out completely.

```
og:url - The canonical URL of your object that will be used as its permanent ID in the graph, e.g., http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117500/.
```